# How to write an hex file

Tags: bash, shell, file, hex

I have a file which is not "readable" (I mean, you can't open it with a text editor, it's weirdly encoded) but with `hexdump`, you can see some readable things. 
In this file, there is a date. Let's say "05082019". So when i do a `hexdump -C` i see this date, and the hex code associated: 3035303832303139

My goal is to write another file exactly like the first one, but with another date in it.

I've tried a simple sed on that date, like:

```
sed 's/05082019/04102022/g' myfile > newfile
```

But, since the file is "weirdly encoded", it seems `sed` can't find the date in it. So i've tried with hexdump:

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' myfile | sed 's/3035303832303139/3034313032303232/g' > newfile
```

But that was a bit stupid: it's writing the hex string in newfile, giving it a totally different value.

i've also tried to change directly the file, like that:

```
cp myfile newfile
 hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' newfile | sed -i 's/3035303832303139/3034313032303232/g'
```

But here `sed -i` is waiting for an input file.

Is there a way to write a file knowing only his hex value? (Or do you have another idea to solve that problem?)

(Note that this should be done in bash script. I'm sorry i can't give any encoded file as example.)

Comment: `sed -i` isn't useful with standard input; `sed` doesn't know which file its input ultimately came from, and so cannot write back to it.

Comment: Editing binary file is something you should do with a general-purpose programming language, not tools designed for working with *text*.

Comment: Try https://hexed.it/?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Please try `xxd -p` to convert binary file to
ascii representation and `xxd -p -r` to do the reverse.

```
xxd -p myfile | tr -d $'\n' | sed 's/3035303832303139/3034313032303232/g' | xxd -p -r > newfile
```

will do what you want.
Note that if your file size exceeds line length limitation of `sed` (depends on the sed version) the approach above may not work. Then please try a `perl` solution as an alternative:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/05082019/04102022/' myfile > newfile
```

Unlike `sed`, `perl` can natively deal with binary files.

Comment: this is great, thank you! can you just explain the `tr -d  $'\n'` part? As far as i understand it, it should delete the last newline in the file. Why is it necessary? won't it change the file at the end?

Comment: Good to hear it works. The pointed part merges all lines by removing trailing newlines of each line.  The output of `xxd` may be split into multiple lines and the target string may be split as well. Then the sed substitution will not work. The process is a countermeasure for it.

Answer (score 2):

### Replicating the File

If you use `hexdump -C $file` and get `3035303832303139`, then $file MUST contain the plaintext `05082019` with no "special encoding".

We can replicate this file like so:

```
$ printf "Here are some random words 05082019 around the date" > myfile
```

### Replacing Date With sed

You were on the right track, you just added an extra `> newfile`. Replacing it inline is then a matter of using `sed -i`.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/05082019/04102022/g' myfile
```

**Note**: -e used for compatibility between Macos/GNU sed.

### Verify

```
$ cat myfile
Here are some random words 04102022 around the date
```

Comment: you are totally right. The date was present in the file without encoding, and i saw it...i guess it was just the end of the day. As for the `sed`, i've tried it with `-i` yesterday too...i just didn't realize there were extra 0 in it just in this particular file, so it didn't work. Now it's alright. Feel like i make you loose your time, sorry, but thanks for the answer.